# Meteor 0.8 and &#2122 escaping

Tags: meteor

Under meteor 0.7, ampersand-escaped codes worked, as in the following example.

```
<template name="navHeader">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="brand" href="/">Company&#8482 Product&#8482</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teams<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Recent Team 1</a>
```

Under meteor 0.8, this tosses an error:

```
 Invalid numerical character reference starting with &#
```

I've looked through meteor and blaze documentation but have not found the solution--is there an easy fix to make this work?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character escapes must end in `;`. This should work:

```html
<a class="brand" href="/">Company&#8482; Product&#8482;</a>
```